# how to save new NSMutableDictionary to a property list

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, dictionary, property-list

i've got this method here which runs through every time I press save:

```
-(void)setName:(NSString *)foodName andCarbs:(NSNumber *)carbAmount{
    [self.userFoodDictionary setObject:(NSString *)foodName forKey:(NSString *)foodName];
    NSString *value = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ Value", foodName];
    [self.userFoodDictionary setObject:(NSNumber *)carbAmount forKey:(NSString *)value];
    [self.userFoodDictionary writeToFile:self.appDataPath atomically:YES];
}
```

From my understanding, the second last line should save the `userFoodDictionary` properties to the specified property list path. But that doesn't seem to happen once. I rebuild the application. Maybe my way of creating a new dictionary object is incorrect. Could someone please explain why this isn't working?

Comment: What is your self.appDataPath?? everything is write but don't know about your path.

Comment: How did you initialize your mutable dictionary?

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@, %@", self.userFoodDictionary, self.appDataPath);` show the log result please.

Comment: And check the return value of `writeToFile:...`

Comment: self.appDataPath is a @property and is created like this: NSString *appDataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"UserFoodData" ofType:@"plist"];

Comment: dictionary is init like this self.userFoodDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:appDataPath];

Comment: How would i check the return value?

Comment: here are the log results 2014-01-24 16:35:58.063 Carbies[1509:70b] {
    Apple = Apple;
    "Apple Value" = 1;
}, (null)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS : I can't write my file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016371/ios-i-cant-write-my-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write to Plist

```
- (NSString *)foodDataPlistFilePath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UserFoodData.plist"];

    return filePath;
}
```

...

```
-(void)setName:(NSString *)foodName andCarbs:(NSNumber *)carbAmount{
    [self.userFoodDictionary setObject:(NSString *)foodName forKey:(NSString *)foodName];
    NSString *value = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ Value", foodName];
    [self.userFoodDictionary setObject:(NSNumber *)carbAmount forKey:(NSString *)value];
    NSString *filePath = [self foodDataPlistFilePath];
    [self.userFoodDictionary writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

Initialize mutable dictionary:

```
NSString *filePath = [self foodDataPlistFilePath];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
self.userFoodDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
if(fileExists){
    NSDictionary *foodData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [_userFoodDictionary setDictionary:foodData];
}
```

Comment: Should i bee seeing changes in my plist file?

Comment: You should be after `[self.userFoodDictionary writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];`

Comment: should NSDictionary be NSMutableDictionary?

Comment: aslo filepath is apparently an unused variable

Comment: You mean the variable `foodData`? It doesn't need to be mutable.

Comment: Which `filePath` is unused? First, second, or third block of code?

Comment: second block of code should i mention i have set filePath and userFoodDictionary with @property

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45979/discussion-between-yoninja-and-mutch95)

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the file in bundle.

As you said in comment, you init self.appDataPath:

```
NSString *appDataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"UserFoodData" ofType:@"plist"];
```

and save the file to the path which is in bundle.

If you would modify the plist file in bundle, you could save the file in app's document.

You can get the document path through:

```
NSString *documentPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

then you combine it with your filename, then get the `filePath`.

`NSString * filePath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UserFoodData.plist"];`

At last you can save it:

`[self.userFoodDictionary writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];`

Comment: How am i able to add objects to the plist then?

Comment: @Mutch95 You should save the file to your app's document or library directory. You can get the document path like this `NSString *documentPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];`

Comment: now my values return 2014-01-24 16:41:27.167 Carbies[1550:70b] (null), (null) when I iterate through

Comment: @Mutch95 Edited, what's `values` reference?